# Magento Manage Attribute Sets Loads Empty Page

Tags: magento, attributes, e-commerce

When I click on an attribute set to edit/configure it, Magento loads an empty page. I have searched on here and Google to find a solution, and have tried changing the memory_limit and max_execution_time with no success.

The page I see has the Magento Admin Panel header/footer with all the CSS, but in-between is empty.

I have also tried flushing the cache, etc.

I am using Magento 1.7 Community Edition.

Comment: Did you check error logs? I mean server logs and the shop logs. If there are no logs under your_shop_root/var/log, enable them under `configuration/developer/log settings`

Comment: I turned on logs, and tried accessing the manage attribute sets page again, checked /var/ but there is no log directory.

Comment: that is strange, try to create the log folder manually

Comment: I created the log folder, but its clearly not saving any log files there. Is there a setting I'm missing? I checked and logs are enabled, and set to save in /var/log

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: It's on shared hosting so I don't have control over that, but its PHP version 5.2.17.

Comment: Checkout this thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/214093/ This may help you

Comment: I don't think thats the problem. I tried the suggestions there, editing the Grid.php file, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: try adding this to the top of your index.php:
ini_set('display_errors', 1); Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
it should give you a better clue/error

Answer (score 1):

Does it look like that ? http://www.magentocommerce.com/?ACT=25&fid=10915&aid=26491_ZqIJgFakZKbxKEik4Iby&board_id=1

In my case the French translation caused the problem (a string was bad escaped and caused a Javascript error). Maybe try to switch to English using the dropdown in the bottom left of the admin area.

I've just installed the [new language pack](http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community%20Mage_Locale_fr_FR) and now it's working again in French.

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_Locale_fr_FR --force
```

Comment: I exactly had the same problem. I just replaced all ' by \' in the csv translation file. Didn't know there was a new language pack.
Btw the problem only exist on Windows, not in Linux